# Web scraping issue with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from this [URL](http://www.egazette.com.sg/gazetteViewDetail.aspx?ct=gg&sc=Ads&year=2020&subscriber=1&stages=3%3E) but while loading the URL with **selenium** it doesn't load this URL instead it take to login page but the data i want is public.

```
path = "C:/Users/gyaan/Desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('http://www.egazette.com.sg/gazetteViewDetail.aspx?ct=gg&sc=Ads&year=2020&subscriber=1&stages=3')
```

> please solve this or suggest what to do to open the URL i am passing directly

Comment: Are you sure this is the right link?  When I follow it, I also get the login-page.

Comment: yes i visited to the area where i want the data from this is the url. what is the issue why it asking me to login as it is public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link, as one of the users pointed out is a log-in page. It may be that you are already logged in on your browser, so you do not see the log-in page. It is not a public page.

You can set up Selenium to type the login credentials for you. I would look into doing that.

Alternatively, if it is one of the "archives" pages, you could configure Selenium to navigate to the page the same way that you would.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in, it should just work, you dont have to log in. I can see the page doesn't have a "remember me" check box, but if you have that page open on another browser window, it will work without logging in.

PS You put beautifulsoup in tags, but using selenium.